# where to add code to display short description in review page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, review

Our [Review page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form) displaying same as [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) except short description.

when i add below code in `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view.phtml`

it didn't displayed short description in review page.

when i use template path hints, it gave like [this](http://sb.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form)

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
<div class="short-description">
<div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

or

```
 <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getShortDescription()); ?>
```

complete code of review/product/view.phtml

```
    <!-- Short Description -->

<?php 
//  echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductData()->getShortDescription());     
//  $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductData()->getId()); echo $pro->getShortDescription();

echo $this->getProductData()->getShortDescription();
?>

<p>test</p>
<!-- Short Description -->

<?php if($this->getProductData()->getId()): ?>
<div class="product-review">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Review Details') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="product-img-box">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductData()->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProductData(), 'small_image')->resize(450, 450)->keepFrame(false); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?>"
                 class="product-image" />
        </a>
        <?php if( $this->getRating() && $this->getRating()->getSize()): ?>
             <p class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Average Customer Rating') ?>:</p>
             <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProductData()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductData()->getName()) ?></h2>
        <?php if( $this->getRating() && $this->getRating()->getSize()): ?>
            <h3><?php echo $this->__('Product Rating:') ?></h3>
            <table class="ratings-table">
            <?php foreach ($this->getRating() as $_rating): ?>
                <?php if($_rating->getPercent()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode())) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($_rating->getPercent()) ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <?php echo $this->__('Product Review (submitted on %s):', $this->dateFormat($this->getReviewData()->getCreatedAt())) ?>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($this->getReviewData()->getDetail())) ?>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBackUrl() ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back to Product Reviews') ?></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Review**

[image]

**Product view**

[image]

Comment: you want to show the description in review section?

Comment: @QaisarSatti i want to display `short description` in top of the review page as like product view page.

Comment: did you try `echo  $this->getProductData()->getShortDescription()`

Comment: @QaisarSatti just tried that, but did't worked for me.

Comment: @QaisarSatti sorry, did't worked for me.

Comment: which file you are adding this code?

Comment: `Review Page` and `Product page` are loaded from SAME template file `catalog/product/view.phtml`. No need to add/load model. Check answer below

Comment: @QaisarSatti i added in this file `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view.phtml`

Comment: `echo $this->getProductData()->getShortDescription();` this is working for me.  adding it `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/view.phtml`

Comment: @BabyinMagento there is no file in that path `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view.phtml`

Comment: @QaisarSatti sorry, its typo, i also added here : `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/view.phtml` . for you everything will work boss.

Comment: @BabyinMagento did you get the output you want?

Comment: @QaisarSatti no, for me it didt worked.

Comment: are  you sure you are editing the correct file?

Comment: @QaisarSatti i am sure about it. i added in top of the file. also when i used `<p> test </p> it didt displayed any text also on top.

Comment: can you add the updated code in question ?

Comment: @QaisarSatti please check updated question.

Comment: @BabyinMagento also check product have short description

Comment: @QaisarSatti short description is displaying for product in product view page [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: do you have any product with review?

Comment: @QaisarSatti you can check here : [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: you are editing this page http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/view/id/4/  it is showing there

Comment: @QaisarSatti this is [template path hint](http://sb.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form) , please tell me where to add the code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41498/discussion-on-question-by-baby-in-magento-where-to-add-code-to-display-short-des).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are editing the wrong file 
add your code in this file.
`frontend/rwd/Stylebaby/template/review/product/view/list.phtml`

use this code

```
<?php  
            $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId()); echo $prod->getShortDescription();
  ?>
```

Comment: sorry , it didt worked for me. i added the code in list.phtml : [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form)

Comment: @BabyinMagento updated and tested too

Comment: now its displaying reviews under middle of the page as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form) . 

I want to display it on top as like product view page [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) also in product view page its displaying 2 times,  in middle & in top , i want to remove in middle.

Comment: @BabyinMagento now it is a css related thing can't help on that

Comment: got the perfect file : app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view/other.phtml when i used your code

it giving error as `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in` but `<p>test</p>`  is working fine.

Comment: when i use this code in same file `echo $this->getProductData()->getShortDescription();` it giving this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getShortDescription() on a non-object in`

Comment: `echo $_product->getShortDescription();` use that

Comment: it gave this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getShortDescription() on a non-object in`

Comment: kindly add it after this  `$_product = Mage::registry('product');`  line

Comment: No error displaying now. but short description not visible.

Comment: try this `<?php  
            $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); echo $prod->getShortDescription();
  ?>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-write `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View` block (or move to `local` codepool) and update below function :

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
//Comment this line
//$this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null);

return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Note: `$this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null);` is commented.

Comment: @Baby in Magento: have you tried this ?

Comment: i will check & let you know. thanks for support.

Comment: got perfect file : `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view/other.phtml `  when i use this code `echo $this->getProductData()->getShortDescription();`  it giving this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getShortDescription() on a non-object in` but html code `<p>test</p>` is displaying at right place.

Comment: You CAN'T get short description in ANY template file under `review_product` block, BECAUSE it's set to `NULL` from the block shown in this answer. You have to comment that line

Comment: if you want to add to `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view/other.phtml` (**NOT RECOMMENDED**), add this line : `<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getShortDescription(); ?>` after `<?php $_product = Mage::registry('product'); ?>`

Comment: i tried above code, i got this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in`

Comment: AFTER this line : `<?php $_product = Mage::registry('product'); ?>`

Comment: sorry boss, dont know how to copy paste, now check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form) no error, but no short description visible